# Dropdown menu difficult to click MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, materialize

I'm having some trouble with MaterializeCSS.

I'm trying to make a navbar which has a dropdown button (the image of the user and a down arrow) to display other options.

The problem is that the submenu, will only be dropped down when I click on the border of the image, not when I click on any part of the button.

This is the code that I use to make the dropdown button in the navbar:

```
<li style="height: 100%">
<a class="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown-users" data-beloworigin="true" style="height: 100%;">
<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/account_friend_human_man_member_person_profile_user_users-256.png" class="" style="height: 100%;">
<i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
</a>
</li>
```

You can see my complete code here: https://codepen.io/JPYamamoto/pen/qmjdmX

I hope you can help me figure this out. Thank you

Comment: I'm not using more css, just the MaterializeCSS framework

Comment: @ChrisHappy it's all in the Codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The a tag that triggers the menu is covered by the image and drop down icon. So i added a span and made it the trigger.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/blecaf/pen/gWRaLY)**

```
<ul id="dropdown-users" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">Submenu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Submenu 2</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Submenu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper blue lighten-1">
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse hide-on-med-and-down"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <a href="index.php" class="brand-logo" style="height: 100%"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Suitcase_icon.svg/1280px-Suitcase_icon.svg.png" style="height: 100%; padding-left: 20px"></a>
        <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down right" style="height: 100%">
            <li><a href="index.php"><i class="material-icons">home</i></a></li>
            <li><a href="films.php">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="planets.php">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="people.php">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="species.php">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="starships.php">Menu 5</a></li>
            <li style="height: 100%"><a style="height: 100%; position:relative"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/account_friend_human_man_member_person_profile_user_users-256.png" class="" style="height: 100%;"><i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i><span  class="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown-users" data-beloworigin="true"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
span.dropdown-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;right:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0; 
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you